# Linear velocity word problems?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me solve these  word problems.

1. An automobile tire has a diameter of 30 inches how fast (r/m) does the wheel turn on the axle when the automobile maintains a speed of 45 mi/h?
2. If an automobile wheel 78 cm in diameter rotates 600 r/min what is the speed of the car in km/h?

Comment: I know the radius for the second one is 39 so would I use the formula for v=r(omega)?

Answer (score 1):

The circumference of the wheel is $2.5\pi$ feet. At $45$ miles per hour, we are travelling at $\frac{(45)(5280)}{60}$ feet per minute.

So if $s$ is the number of revolutions per minute, we have
$$(2.5\pi)s=\frac{(45)(5280)}{60},$$
and therefore
$$s=\frac{(45)(5280)}{(60)(2.5\pi)}.$$
The rest can be done by calculator.

The other problem involves more or less the same ideas, but is a little easier. The circumference of the tire is $78\pi$ cm. At $600$ rpm, we travel $(78\pi)(600)$ cm per minute. This is $(78\pi)(600)(60)$ cm per hour. To convert to km per hour, divide by the number of cm in $1$ km, which is $100000$.

Comment: I calculated, got $504.20286$. Maybe a glitch in handling the calculator?

Comment: how would I set up the second problem.I see I made a calc error with the first one.

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: The final answer in my book is 88.2

Comment: I get $88.215922$. If you don't, you are not handling the calculator correctly.