# Angular velocity question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linear velocity word problems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162985/linear-velocity-word-problems)

How would I solve the following problem?

If a car wheel 78 cm in diameter rotates at 600 r/min what is the speed of the car in km/h?

Comment: I added the solution of this to your previous question, which included this one.

Comment: Nobody told you that it has contact with the ground...

Answer (score 1):

radius of the wheel=$0.39$m. Angular velocity=$600*2\pi/60$ rad/sec.Assuming the case of pure rolling,  velocity=$r*\omega$ = $20*0.39.\pi \approx 24.5 m/sec = 88.2 km/hr$.